# PDO::FETCH_GROUP is returning duplicated values for each row, why?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP) to grab every row in my database and split them by product type. However, when running it, I am getting duplicate results? So for example, instead of getting:

```
id: "0"
img_url: "products/doors/french.png"
subproduct: "French Doors"
```

I am getting the result:

```
0: "0"
1: "French Doors"
2: "products/doors/french.png"
id: "0"
img_url: "products/doors/french.png"
subproduct: "French Doors"
```

It is extremely strange behaviour and I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening? If I change the Fetch type to only grab specific rows, it grabs them okay, but if I try and use Fetch_Group, I get the above results.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=allproducts', 'root', '');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Sorry, database problem");
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "allproducts");
$response = array();
if($handler){
    $response = $handler->query('SELECT product, id, subproduct, img_url from allproducts')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

} else {
    echo "Not connected";
}
echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: Do `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` You can combine fetch modes. Read https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes

Comment: Don't mix mysqli and PDO. Pick one and use only one extension.